# Is there a specific term for an area of different IT systems?

Tags: terminology

I would like to know the technical term for the following situation, if there is any:

You are developing in a field, where a set of different hardware types (like iPhone5, Galaxy S3) are running different software of the same type (like a browser) and the capabilities of the hardware impact the software capabilities

How can I state this scenario in a short way?

- The systems are fragmented
- Developing for heterogenous systems
- Developing for diversify systems

I am not sure if any of those examples above is an appropriate description. My guts tell me, that there is a specific term for this scenario in the area of IT- and Software-Architecture language.

Comment: Sounds like a CV question and not an SO question.

Comment: it's for a report paper, but I guess it could be useful in a CV too - for me it's a question about technical terminology

Comment: I am aware, that this is not a programming problem, however, it is programming related, as you have to describe your work and problems to executives; I've hoped SO would be the right place to quickly get an anwser (practical, answerable problems that are unique to software development) - I am interested in suggestions, to where on StackExchange I should have posted this instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say *distributed cross-platform cross-device application*.

- distributed - when the application uses a network
- cross-platform - when the application is aware of multiple platforms, for example it works on unix and windows as well
- cross-device - when the application is aware of different hardware types, for example it displays a metro gui by touchscreen and normal webpage by mouse + keyboard
- cross-browser - when the application runs in a browsers, and it is aware of different browser types, for example it uses CORS by firefox and chrome, but by msie it tries an alternative approach to connect to the server, or displays a fallback
- heterogeneous system - when you application uses different hardware and software types to achieve its goal, for example it has a php frontend tier and a java backend tier, etc...
- polyglot - when the application uses multiple programming languages to achieve its goals, for example by polyglot persistence you use nosql and sql databases as well

Comment: +1 - thanks, although I'll keep on looking, this already helps and might be just it; however, I still have the feeling there might an even more spericif terminology out there, so I'll wait a bit until accepting something

Answer (score 1):

Would it be suitable in this case to say you're simple developing for different platforms?

Taking this further you might talk about 'stacks', for example a tablet might use the 'MEAN' stack (MongoDB, ExpressJS, AngularJS and NodeJS), the Windows platform might use a .NET stack (ASP MVC, WCF, MSSQL), the Ubuntu platform might use a Java stack etc etc.

Comment: I would like to incorporate more information into the sentence, because it has to be short but informative - just stating that there are different platforms does not give an image about the impact of that. e.g.: a Java-App runs on different Platforms without a big difference, while a WebPage might behave quite differently although on the same platform, just because of a different Browser, but also differntly on different platforms, like on a mobile device  (now state that in a short precise way - ?!)